# How to use delimiter to isolate words (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am writing a program that scans text files and then writes each word into a Hashmap.

The Scanner class has a defualt delimiter of space. But I ended up having my words stored with punctuations attached to them. I want the scanner to recognize periods, comas and other types of common punctuations as a sign to stop the token. Here's what I have attempted:

```
    Scanner line_scanner = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("[.,:;()?!\" \t]+~\\s");
```

The scanner basically ignored all the spaces even though I have '\\s' as part of the expression. Sorry, but I have hardly any understanding of regex.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Scanner line_scanner = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("[.,:;()?!\"\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might go for no unicode letters:

```
useDelimiter("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]+");
```

([^...] is not, Capital p means Unicode category, L are the letters, M the diacritical combining marks (accents).)